# Change field value using cglib

Tags: java, reflection, cglib

Suppose we have object `field` of class `java.lang.reflect.Field`. It is possible to change value of that field of object `o1` to the value of `o2``s field by `field.set(o1, o2)`. I am wondering whether it can be done faster with the help of some library, for example cglib?

Answer (score 0):

No, the JVM implements a JIT compiler which makes byte code generation obsolete for performance in 99.9% of the cases. In the case of reflection, people sometime use code generation to avoid the security checks that the reflection API implies. Rather than that, you should look into `MethodHandle`s which moves this security check to the handle creation such that it is not triggered on each call.